# Laravel 5.4: Ckeditor.js not load on the view (blade.php)

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

**My Script does not load ckeditor.js on the view (file.blade.php)**

Details:

My Laravel 5.4 Folder structure(partial) is as below.

```
-example.com
----Ckeditor
-------ckeditor.js
----Public //this is the document root of example.com
----Resources
-------Views
----------file.blade.php
```

I have called ckeditor.js on demo.blade.php like this...

Method 1:

```
<script src="{{url('Ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}"></script>
```

Method 2:

```
<script src="http://example.com/Ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

No Method loads ckeditor.js on file.blade.php

How should I do this?

Comment: Are you able to access the JS file via browser ? like : http://example.com/Ckeditor/ckeditor.js

Answer (score 2):

Put Ckeditor folder into public folder and include js the into view like:

```
<script src="{{asset('Ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}"></script>
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-asset

Comment: Thanks it worked when I put this code on the text area control inside.